# R programme: new variable from the sum of the greater values of other col

Tags: r

i have been trying to find the solution of this but i couldnt find the solution. I have the next dataframe:

```
GROUP   HEIGT   WEIGHT
 1       1.6      66
 1       1.5      74
 1       1.8      82
 2       1.9      85
 2        hi      wi
 2
 2
 3
 ...
```

And i want to create a new variable "WEIGHTsum" **per group**.
This variable is the sum of the weights of people (of the same group) with height`s larger than the subject person´s height.

For example:

```
GROUP   NAME    HEIGT   WEIGHT  WEIGHTsum
 1      Phil     1.6      74      82     (only Matt is taller than him)
 1      Ross     1.5      66      74+82  (Matt + Phil weight)    
 1      Matt     1.8      82      0      (Nobody is taller in group 1)
 2      Sam      1.9      85      0      (Nobody is taller in group 2)
 2      Peter    1.6      71      77+85  (Sam + Marie weight)
 2      Marie    1.8      77      85     (only Sam is taller in g2)
 2      Carla    1.5      65     71+77+85  (everyone is taller in g2)
 3
```

Thanks and sorry if i explained the problem bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base solution assuming your data is in a `data.frame` called `df`, you could do something like this:

```
df = df[order(df$GROUP),] #make sure it is well ordered
df$WEIGHTsum = unlist(
    by(df, df$GROUP, function(y) #by group
         sapply(y$HEIGT, FUN = function(x) #for each weight
                sum(y[x < y$HEIGT, ]$WEIGHT)))) #sum applicable weights

  GROUP  NAME HEIGT WEIGHT WEIGHTsum
1     1  Phil   1.6     74        82
2     1  Ross   1.5     66       156
3     1  Matt   1.8     82         0
4     2   Sam   1.9     85         0
5     2 Peter   1.6     71       162
6     2 Marie   1.8     77        85
7     2 Carla   1.5     65       233
```

**edit:** thanks to @thelatemail, I realized that you would need a well-ordered `data.frame` to ensure that this solution will return a proper result.

Comment: Be careful however, as this assumes that you have ordered your dataset by `GROUP` in the same order that `by()` processes the groups.

Comment: Could you elaborate @thelatemail? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: `by` is similar to `tapply` in that the order of returned results is not the same order as the input necessarily - `x <- 1:5; cbind(x, unlist(by(x, c(1,2,1,2,1), FUN=identity)))`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think my edit should work around that situation.

Comment: This solution will also be extremely slow on a larger data set. I expanded the data set for 200,000 rows and it has not finished after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one solution that I could think of with library `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(GROUP, desc(WEIGHT)) %>% group_by(GROUP) %>% mutate(WEIGHTsum = cumsum(WEIGHT) - WEIGHT)

Source: local data frame [7 x 5]

  GROUP  NAME HEIGT WEIGHT WEIGHTsum
  (int) (chr) (dbl)  (int)     (int)
1     1  Matt   1.8     82         0
2     1  Phil   1.6     74        82
3     1  Ross   1.5     66       156
4     2   Sam   1.9     85         0
5     2 Marie   1.8     77        85
6     2 Peter   1.6     71       162
7     2 Carla   1.5     65       233
```

It used ordering, cumusum and then netting out the current row's weight. If I think of a simpler way to do it, I will edit. Others may have ideas.

Answer (score 3):

`data.table` attempt using `.EACHI` to compare each value of weight against the set of values in each `GROUP`:

```
setDT(dat)
setkey(dat,GROUP)
dat[, WEIGHTsum := dat[dat, sum(WEIGHT[HEIGT > i.HEIGT]), by=.EACHI]$V1]
dat

   GROUP  NAME HEIGT WEIGHT WEIGHTsum
1:     1  Phil   1.6     74        82
2:     1  Ross   1.5     66       156
3:     1  Matt   1.8     82         0
4:     2   Sam   1.9     85         0
5:     2 Peter   1.6     71       162
6:     2 Marie   1.8     77        85
7:     2 Carla   1.5     65       233
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick function to do this. It's pretty easy to follow the logic.

```
GetWeightSum = function(data){
  WEIGHTsum = numeric(nrow(data))
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    currentgroup = data[i,1]
    tmp = data[data$GROUP == currentgroup,] ##gets a data frame of everyone in the same group
    ws = 0 
    for(j in 1:nrow(tmp)){
      if((tmp[j,3] > data[i,3])){ ##this only works for strictly greater so each individual won't contribute
        ws = ws + tmp[j,4]      ##to their own weight sum or people with their exact same height
      }
    }
    WEIGHTsum[i] = ws
  }
  return(cbind(data,WEIGHTsum))
}
```

Results:

```
GROUP  NAME HEIGHT WEIGHT WEIGHTsum
1     1  Phil    1.6     74        82
2     1  Ross    1.5     66       156
3     1  Matt    1.8     82         0
4     2   Sam    1.9     85         0
5     2 Peter    1.6     71       162
6     2 Marie    1.8     77        85
7     2 Carla    1.5     65       233
```